# How to open TestComplete from java code

Tags: java, runtime.exec, testcomplete

I would like to open TestComplete from java, but I can't do that, because lack of privilege. When I run my code

```
public static void StartTC() {
    try{
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SmartBear\\TestComplete 11\\Bin\\TestComplete.exe"});
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the program exits with CreateProcess error=740, and tells me that I need higher privilege for this action.
I know that I could make a .lnk with admin priv. at open properties of the exe, but there could be a right way to do this.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the *Tools | Options... | Engines | General | **Enable support for testing Windows Store applications*** option in TestComplete.

Information on how this can affect working with TestComplete from an external application like in your case can be found in the [Requirements for Testing Windows Store Applications](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/70880/) help topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use File class for setting permissions.

```
 File file = new File("File.c");
 //but file permission are OS specific.
 file.setExecutable(true);
```

In linux it will work.

If you are using windows then you can run "icacls" command to give permission to the file.

```
C:\>icacls "D:\test" /grant John:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

This command can be used to to give permission in windows.

```
According do MS documentation:

F = Full Control
CI = Container Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate containers will inherit this ACE.
OI = Object Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate files will inherit the ACE.
/T = Apply recursively to existing files and sub-folders. (OI and CI only apply to new files and sub-folders). Credit: comment by @AlexSpence.
```

You can run above command using  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("icacls something here");

`I hope I helped you`.

Comment: I've tried with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("icacls F <file path>"), and ("icacls /grant user.name:(OI)(CI)F <file path>"), but it just do nothing for me. No error message, but the TestComplete is still not open.

Comment: Are you sure command not throwing any error message? Try to get errorStream from the command you have executed or try to run command from command line (CMD) then run your code, it may work.